# Android music player lock screen

Tags: android, lockscreen, android-music-player

A few days ago I updated my Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini's android version and saw a new feature when I locked my screen while the music player was playing. I always used the amazon media player to play my music. It has a custom lock widget. However, now it has two?! The old custom one and a new one. However, the "new" one is the same when I use different media players. It sets the background image to the album art of the current song and 3 buttons to control the playback.

[This is a picture of how it looks like when I play music with almost any media player I have (except my self made one) and lock the screen.](http://i582.photobucket.com/albums/ss269/netbookc/XB1/XperiaSICSFirmware_06.png)

How do I let my player use this apparently default lock screen widget to control my media playback?

Edit:
I am not talking about a player I downloaded. I am creating my own music player.

Comment: This question is completely off-topic and belongs on http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I asked and they told me that THIS is the right place to ask. I can only agree with them. [link to my question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/76959/android-default-lock-screen-controls-for-music-player)

Comment: Your question sounds like you ask on how to configure the media player you are using. If you want to add this functionality to your own app you should edit your question to make it more clear. In the current state it would still be off topic (see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center).

Comment: You might want to check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441626/android-lock-screen-and-keyboard-controls). The sample code [can be found here](http://docs.eoeandroid.com/resources/samples/RandomMusicPlayer/src/com/example/android/musicplayer/index.html).

Comment: Current documentation for the used class: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RemoteControlClient.html